# jQuery: $(this) vs. this.$()

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, ember.js

In Ember.js's [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/asynchrony/), they have a jQuery code snippet with the following syntax:

```
this.$().button();
```

Is this snippet only turning `this` into a jQuery object so that the jQuery UI `.button()` function can be called on it?

Would this snippet be identical?

```
$(this).button();
```

Comment: The first snippet suggests that the jQuery object ($) is stored as a property on `this`, possibly to avoid polluting global scope, but I'm not sure.

Comment: But it's executed. And it returns, so it's chained. I think that's legit, but I would never have thought of trying that ...

Comment: does this.button() work? If so, 'this' is a jquery object.

Comment: Well, I just tested the "random this with jquery() as a function on it" and of course, as expected, that doesn't work

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/332d2146f6f4da2008546665f33513a0cc4ea876/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1065-1078) explains this as follows:

```
/**
    Returns a jQuery object for this view's element. If you pass in a selector
    string, this method will return a jQuery object, using the current element
    as its buffer.

    For example, calling `view.$('li')` will return a jQuery object containing
    all of the `li` elements inside the DOM element of this view.

    @param {String} [selector] a jQuery-compatible selector string
    @returns {Ember.CoreQuery} the CoreQuery object for the DOM node
  */
  $: function(sel) {
    return this.invokeForState('$', sel);
  },
```

So to answer your question: no it's not the same as `$(this)`, which would wrap the ember view instance in a jQuery object...

Comment: Thanks.  That is exactly the answer I was looking for.